# Sailing Around the World on a Jet Stream

Tags: weather-forecasting, air-currents, jet-stream

An ultra light plane can stay in flight up to 2400 km (the World Record) with out an engine using thermal lift. Can a huge kite like airship (not a blimp) be built to indefinitely sail in and out of the jet stream orbiting the Earth somewhat like the ship off Peter Pan? 
[image]

This is a possible route that could be taken on this day's jet stream chart shown below.